# Parse error, unexpected STRING_LITERAL, expecting PIPE or ROW VHDL

Tags: vhdl, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, xilinx

I am trying to implement 32x32 Register File in VHDL. I have been struggling with this issue for a while... More specifically, I get the following error when I try to compile the code:

HDLParsers:164 - "//vmware-host/shared folders/Shared from MAIN/decoder.vhd" Line 26. parse error, unexpected STRING_LITERAL, expecting PIPE or ROW

I have tried variety of different solutions and none of them worked.
I am placing all the entities as they appear in the top level system.
The top level system:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
library work;
use work.array_pkg.all;

entity GenRegisters is

     port( Rd_Data : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
             Rs, Rt, Rd : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
             Reg_Write : in std_logic; -- enable
             Rs_Output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
             Rt_Output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
             CLK, RESET : in std_logic -- clock and reset
            );

end GenRegisters;

architecture Behavioural of GenRegisters is

 signal decoder_out : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 signal DOUT: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);


    -- component declaration
    component Register32  
        port (
                DIN : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- system inputs
                DOUT : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- system outputs
                ENABLE : in std_logic_vector (0 downto 0); -- enable
                CLK, RESET : in std_logic -- clock and reset
                ); 

    end component; -- end component;


       -- component declaration
    component Mux32t5
        port (
                Registers : in array2d; -- system inputs
                Rselect : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
                Rout : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) -- system outputs
                ); 

    end component; -- end component;

       -- component declaration
    component decoder 
        port (
                enable : in std_logic; -- enable
                binary_in: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); -- system inputs
                decoder_out: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) -- system outputs
                ); 

    end component; -- end component;




    begin
      -- VHDL Generalte  allows you to replicate  components, see hep


        Decoder_1: decoder 
        port map(Reg_write, Rd, decoder_out); 




       GEN_ADD: for I in 0  to 31 generate

          Register32D:Register32  port  map  

            (Rd_Data, DOUT, decoder_out(I), CLK, RESET); -- :)

                    end generate GEN_ADD;  

        Mux_Rt: Mux32t5 
        port map(Register32D, Rt, Rt_Output);                     


        Mux_Rs: Mux32t5 
        port map(Register32D, Rs, Rs_Output); 

    end Behavioural;
```

Decoder entity:

```
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity decoder is
    port(
        enable      :in  std_logic; --  Enable for the decoder
        binary_in   :in  std_logic_vector (4 downto 0); --  5-bit Input
        decoder_out :out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) --  32-bit Output

            );

end decoder;

architecture Behavioural of decoder is

begin
    process (enable, binary_in) 
     begin

        decoder_out <= X"00000000";
        if (enable = '1') then
            case (binary_in) is
                when 5x"00"   => decoder_out <= X"00000001";
                when 5x"01"   => decoder_out <= X"00000002";
                when 5x"02"   => decoder_out <= X"00000004";
                when 5x"03"   => decoder_out <= X"00000008";
                when 5x"04"   => decoder_out <= X"00000010";
                when 5x"05"   => decoder_out <= X"00000020";
                when 5x"06"   => decoder_out <= X"00000040";
                when 5x"07"   => decoder_out <= X"00000080";
                when 5x"08"   => decoder_out <= X"00000100";
                when 5x"09"   => decoder_out <= X"00000200";
                when 5x"0A"   => decoder_out <= X"00000400";
                when 5x"0B"   => decoder_out <= X"00000800";
                when 5x"0C"   => decoder_out <= X"00001000";
                when 5x"0D"   => decoder_out <= X"00002000";
                when 5x"0E"   => decoder_out <= X"00004000";
                when 5x"0F"   => decoder_out <= X"00008000";
                     when 5x"10"   => decoder_out <= X"00010000";
                when 5x"11"   => decoder_out <= X"00020000";
                when 5x"12"   => decoder_out <= X"00040000";
                when 5x"13"   => decoder_out <= X"00080000";
                when 5x"14"   => decoder_out <= X"00100000";
                when 5x"15"   => decoder_out <= X"00200000";
                when 5x"16"   => decoder_out <= X"00400000";
                when 5x"17"   => decoder_out <= X"00800000";
                when 5x"18"   => decoder_out <= X"01000000";
                when 5x"19"   => decoder_out <= X"02000000";
                when 5x"1A"   => decoder_out <= X"04000000";
                when 5x"1B"   => decoder_out <= X"08000000";
                when 5x"1C"   => decoder_out <= X"10000000";
                when 5x"1D"   => decoder_out <= X"20000000";
                when 5x"1E"   => decoder_out <= X"40000000";
                when 5x"1F"   => decoder_out <= X"80000000";
                when others  => decoder_out <= X"00000000";
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioural;
```

Register32:

```
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity Register32 is

port (
                DIN : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- system inputs
                DOUT : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- system outputs
                ENABLE : in std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
                CLK, RESET : in std_logic -- clock and reset
       ); 

end Register32;

architecture Behavioural of Register32 is

begin

    process(CLK,RESET)
        begin -- process
     -- activities triggered by asynchronous reset (active high)
            if RESET = '1' then     DOUT <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
      -- activities triggered by rising edge of clock
                elsif CLK'event and CLK = '1' then
                    if ENABLE='1' then DOUT <= DIN;
                    else null;
                end if;
            end if;
     end process;

end Behavioural;
```

MUX_Rt:

```
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.array_pkg.all;

-- define inputs and outputs

entity Mux32t5 is 
     port(
            Registers : in array2d;
            RSelect : in    std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            Rout    : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) );

    end Mux32t5;


architecture Behavioural of Mux32t5 is
begin
        with Rselect select
                                    Rout <= Registers(0) when 5X"00", 
                                              Registers(1) when 5X"01",
                                              Registers(2) when 5X"02",
                                              Registers(3) when 5X"03",
                                              Registers(4) when 5X"04",
                                              Registers(5) when 5X"05",
                                              Registers(6) when 5X"06",
                                              Registers(7) when 5X"07",
                                              Registers(8) when 5X"08",
                                              Registers(9) when 5X"09",
                                              Registers(10) when 5X"0A",
                                              Registers(11) when 5X"0B",
                                              Registers(12) when 5X"0C",
                                              Registers(13) when 5X"0D",
                                              Registers(14) when 5X"0E",
                                              Registers(15) when 5X"0F",
                                              Registers(16) when 5X"10",
                                              Registers(17) when 5X"11",
                                              Registers(18) when 5X"12",
                                              Registers(19) when 5X"13",
                                              Registers(20) when 5X"14",
                                              Registers(21) when 5X"15",
                                              Registers(22) when 5X"16",
                                              Registers(23) when 5X"17",
                                              Registers(24) when 5X"18",
                                              Registers(25) when 5X"19",
                                              Registers(26) when 5X"1A",
                                              Registers(27) when 5X"1B",
                                              Registers(28) when 5X"1C",
                                              Registers(29) when 5X"1D",
                                              Registers(30) when 5X"1E",
                                              Registers(31) when 5X"1F",
                                              X"0000" when others;

end Behavioural;
```

MUX_Rs:

```
-------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.array_pkg.all;

-- define inputs and outputs

entity Mux32t5 is 
     port(
            Registers : in array2d;
            RSelect : in    std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            Rout    : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) );

    end Mux32t5;


architecture Behavioural of Mux32t5 is
begin
        with Rselect select
                                    Rout <= Registers(0) when 5X"00", 
                                              Registers(1) when 5X"01",
                                              Registers(2) when 5X"02",
                                              Registers(3) when 5X"03",
                                              Registers(4) when 5X"04",
                                              Registers(5) when 5X"05",
                                              Registers(6) when 5X"06",
                                              Registers(7) when 5X"07",
                                              Registers(8) when 5X"08",
                                              Registers(9) when 5X"09",
                                              Registers(10) when 5X"0A",
                                              Registers(11) when 5X"0B",
                                              Registers(12) when 5X"0C",
                                              Registers(13) when 5X"0D",
                                              Registers(14) when 5X"0E",
                                              Registers(15) when 5X"0F",
                                              Registers(16) when 5X"10",
                                              Registers(17) when 5X"11",
                                              Registers(18) when 5X"12",
                                              Registers(19) when 5X"13",
                                              Registers(20) when 5X"14",
                                              Registers(21) when 5X"15",
                                              Registers(22) when 5X"16",
                                              Registers(23) when 5X"17",
                                              Registers(24) when 5X"18",
                                              Registers(25) when 5X"19",
                                              Registers(26) when 5X"1A",
                                              Registers(27) when 5X"1B",
                                              Registers(28) when 5X"1C",
                                              Registers(29) when 5X"1D",
                                              Registers(30) when 5X"1E",
                                              Registers(31) when 5X"1F",
                                              X"0000" when others;
    end Behavioural;
```

array_pkg:
    LIBRARY IEEE;
    USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

```
package array_pkg is

TYPE array2d IS ARRAY(31 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);

END array_pkg;
```

Can anyone provide some clues or solution for the problem please?

Answer (score 2):

For your multiplexor you might consider a simpler alternate solution and replace the case statement with

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all ; 
architecture Behavioural of Mux32t5 is
begin
  ROut <= registers (to_integer(unsigned(binary_in))) ;
end Behavioural ;
```

Or alternately with the unsigned package (note this one requires VHDL-2008):

```
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all ; 
...
ROut <= registers (to_integer(binary_in)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use VHDL-2008 conventions for that case statement and the compiler is not happy with you.  Try this in your decoder.vhd:

```
case (binary_in) is
  when "00000"   => decoder_out <= X"00000001";
  when "00001"   => decoder_out <= X"00000002";
  when "00010"   => decoder_out <= X"00000004";
  when "00011"   => decoder_out <= X"00000008";
```

Etc...

Comment: I have solution for it now. Apparently, the compiler could not recognize the constants e.g. 5X"0F. Instead we used expression 'MSB' & X"Hex" which looks like

if (enable = '1') then
   case (binary_in) is
...
when '0' & x"F"   => decoder_out <= X"00000001";
...

Comment: If you do not have the VHDL-2008 switch on, you will need to remove the parens from your case statement:  case binary_in is

Comment: Make sure to submit a bug report against their lack of support of against the lack of support for the 5X"0F".  Interesting that they do support the when '0' & X"F" => as that requires a much more complicated VHDL-2008 addition.